# The operation couldn't be completed.(com.facebook.sdk error 2.) error iOS 6

Tags: facebook, ios6

I have been using the Facebook login flow example for my app and on previous example apps this login process has worked but now i get the error (com.facebook.sdk error 2.). I am building with iOS 6 and have checked that all id's and bundle indentifiers match.

*Example code*

appdelegate.m

```
    - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");

            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        NSLog(@"Login Failed");
        [alertView show];
    }
}


// Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {


    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_events",
                            @"user_activites",
                            @"user_birthday",



                            nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"\nfb sdk error = %@", error);
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}

/*
 * If we have a valid session at the time of openURL call, we handle
 * Facebook transitions by passing the url argument to handleOpenURL
 */

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    NSLog(@"Found FaceBook");
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

maincontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)authButtonAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"session open");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // If the user is authenticated, log out when the button is clicked.
    // If the user is not authenticated, log in when the button is clicked.
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate closeSession];
    } else {
        // The user has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
        // and show the login UX if necessary.
        [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
    }

}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"Login Activated");
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = authButton;
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        authButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
        authButton.title=@"Login";
    }else{
        authButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
        authButton.title=@"Logout";
    }

    }
```

Any ideas? Is this a Facebook bug or am i missing something?

Comment: I seeing the same issue with already published app!

Comment: @Stephen - Did you find an answer? Thanks.